# 301 Remove Entire last Directory from url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

SCENARIO:
Joomla + SH404

A previous version of a component was adding "/registration" to the event page url to redirect it towards the related registration form.

The new version integrates the form in the same event page. 
The problem is that the Apps still redirects to the previous url and I cannot recode them at this time.

So, I should remove the last part of SEO Url using htaccess

Example:
http://mydomain.ext/category/this-is-my-page/registration

should becomes

http://mydomain.ext/category/this-is-my-page

I tried in htaccess:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /registration(.*) /$1
```

but it redirects to home page

any tips?

Comment: Please check your error log for info about the error.

Comment: Solved the internal server error, but now it redirects to the home page

Comment: The log sows the following error now
[Sun Feb 12 20:36:29 2017] [error] [client 137.74.120.5] cannot redirect '/category/this-is-my-page/registration' to ''; target is not a valid absoluteURI or abs_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked fine for me:

RewriteRule ^(.*)/registration /$1 [R=301,L]

thanks to Ellegi